# How to generate Class Diagram in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

Now , I am working with Visual Studio 2008. I want to Create Class Diagram. I don't want to design the class diagram. I mean I want to generate class diagram automatically by using VS 2008. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the project, choose "View Class Diagram".